# Why has Chrome started to distort the rendering of icons or images?

Tags: google-chrome, image-processing, rendering

When I open a new page and move the mouse, Chrome starts to render icons and images in a distorted way.

For example, right now, the SuperUser Log on *this* page's top is rendered as follows:
[image]

The "toolbar" is rendered like this:
[image]

When I press `F5`, the images are rendered correctly, but as soon as I start to move the mouse, the image become distorted again.

I have the same behavior even after restarting the computer.

I didn't observe the same image distortions in applications other than chrome (but I didn't spend much time investigating either).

What is causing this strange phenomenon?

Comment: If strange things are happening in any web browser, the first step is to clear its cache.

Comment: I have cleared the cache, yet without noticeable effect.

Comment: Does it happen in an Incognito window? If not, then this is an extension problem and you could disable extensions from `chrome://extensions/` until you find the problem. If it still happens in Incognito, I would suggest to uninstall Chrome (saving bookmarks), clean folders and reinstall.

Comment: Does this issue occur in **other** browsers? That would tell you if the issue is in Chrome (then reinstall), or outside, e.g., hardware or OS.